# FXBlurView ios flickering

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm implementing an [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) and it works beautifully, except that when my view scrolls off the screen, it flickers at the edge that is scrolling off screen. I've also tried resizing the FXBlurView in favor of moving it off screen, but that also causes a flicker effect. Anybody else run into this issue?

Comment: I had the same issue and realised that it was the white background colour of my FXBlurView creating the flicker. Changing to clear colour fixed it for me.